# Automatically click an element of a toolstrip

Tags: excel, automation, winspector, vba

Im triying to automate the control of a program. I want to load a big amount of files automatically.

The program loke like this (winspector view and and corresponding api view):

[image]

As you can see, I have 7 element in my toolstrip. What I want to do is to **figure out some way to click the desire element of this toolstrip** (lets call the "n" element)

By doing this:

```
'lhWndP is the parent window handle
toolstriphandl= FindWindowEx(lhWndP, 0&, "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a", "toolStrip1")
```

I get the handle of the toolstrip, but I dont know what to do now.

I tried to do this:

```
toolstripmenu = GetMenu(toolstriphandl)
toolstripmenu = GetSubMenu(toolstripmenu, n)
SendMessage toolstriphandl, WM_COMMAND, toolstripmenu, 0
```

But doesn't seems to work.

Any idea please? Im desperate with this.

Thank you.